# How to hide HTML Element in CSS media print based on input field value

Tags: html, css, angular, user-interface

**`Use Case:`** I have an invoicing application with various fields like Discount, Freight, etc. on the invoice page.

**`Requirement:`** I want to hide these fields from the CSS media print option if the value of any of these fields is set to 0(zero). Because it doesn't make sense to show them on an invoice printing page otherwise clients might get surprised and ask for discounts if they see the empty field.

**So, how can we hide the div based on an input field value in the CSS Media Print?**

**Have a look at the below image to see the invoice page. Also, have a look at CSS media print code to understand it better.**

**`Invoice Page:`**

[image: sample-invoice-page]

**`CSS Media Print Code:`**

```css
@media print {
  html, body {
    height:100vh; 
    margin: 0 !important; 
    padding: 0 !important;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  body * {
    visibility:hidden;
  }

  #printThis, #printThis * {
    visibility:visible;
  }

  .remove-item > a, .add-item > a, .modal-footer {
    display: none;
  }

  .modal {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: visible!important;
  }
```

Comment: if you using angular you can use `*ngIf` in condition you are using a button to apply the print page or use `[ngClass]`

Comment: You can add a CSS `class` on the input field according to its `value` using `ngClass`. And that `class` would be used to `hide` the input field.

Comment: @dt170 thanks for your help. I've used **`[ngClass]`** to solve this query.

Comment: @HassanMoin I wanted to hide the entire div and not just the input element. So, I had to add a class to the div to achieve this. But, thanks for your efforts in writing here to my query.

Answer (score 1):

In the invoice image above, I wanted to hide the entire discount row from the print page if the discount input box value is 0(zero). The row contains 2 different DIVs as below,
**1. For Discount Dropdown
2. For Discount Input element**

**`Solution:`** The change was at 2 places,

1. Add the class to a div dynamically based on the input element value.
2. In the CSS file media print section to hide the class which we have added to our DIVs dynamically.

**Have a look at both the changes below,**

1. Adding CSS class to a div dynamically based on input element value.
   **`Note:`** Here, invoice is a object in my typescript component class.

```html
<div class="col-10 text-end" [class.hide-discount]="((invoice.discountTotal === 0) || (!invoice.discountTotal))">
         Discount: 
       <select class="form-select p-0" style="display: inline; width:60px;" [(ngModel)]="invoice.discountLabel" name="discountLabel" id="discountLabel" aria-label="Select discount option">
              <option value=""></option>
              <option value="%">%</option>
              <option value="Rs">Rs</option>
        </select>
</div>    
 
 <div class="col-2 text-center" [class.hide-discount]="((invoice.discountTotal === 0) || (!invoice.discountTotal))">
        <input [disabled]="(invoice.discountLabel === '')" [(ngModel)]="invoice.discountTotal" name="discountTotal" type="number" style="border: 1px solid #ddd; width:100px">
</div>
```

2. CSS Media Print code with the classes to hide,

```css
@media print {
  html, body {
    height:100vh; 
    margin: 0 !important; 
    padding: 0 !important;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  body * {
    visibility:hidden;
  }

  #printThis, #printThis * {
    visibility:visible;
  }

  .hide-discount {
    display: none;
  }

  .remove-item > a, .add-item > a, .modal-footer {
    display: none;
  }

  .modal {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: visible!important;
  }

}
```